# PHP interaction with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, prototypejs, prototype

So I have this function in my javascript file:

```
function UpdateThisCourseHistory(){
    var ajax= new Ajax.Request("runNeededQueries.php",
            {
                method: "POST",
                parameters: {database: "history", action:"update"},
                onSuccess: function(){alert("This Course History Entry Has Been Updated");},
                onFailure: function(){alert("Could Not Find The Entry With The Specified Primary Key");}        
            }
    );
}
```

Suppose this is my php file

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
 ?>
```

Would this make the onFailure method execute?

Comment: what framework are you using? I'm not remembering having this Ajax object in plain javascript.

Comment: What do you mean the php code fails?

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery... It makes AJAX VERY simple.

Comment: Ajax doesnt depend on remote function pass or fail, it just makes a call to it and returns back the appropriate response back.

Comment: @Sebas: Prototype. alexander7567:While jQuery is good, it is not the answer to _everything_.

Comment: Return response headers from php script.

Comment: @alexander7567: this isnt about Ajax functionality, here the user is interpreting in wrong way.

Comment: Looks like Prototype, but the OP should confirm that.

Comment: @dreamweiver I understand that now that I seen Explosion Pills's comment

Comment: Yes i am using prototype

Comment: @alexander7567, ajax is ANYWAY very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onSuccess callback will fire when the PHP script responds with an HTTP 2xx response code and the onFailure callback will fire if an HTTP error code is returned. If you want to take action based on the response value, you have to options:

- Modify your PHP script to return an HTTP error response (perhaps 400) on failure and take action based on the specific value returned.

  - `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');`
- Update your AJAX handler to inspect the data that is returned and take action based on its content.

  - `onSuccess: function(transport){ if transport.responseText == 'expected value' ...}`

Comment: @user2366551 You can use `header()` to set the response code. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: I would definitely go for the second solution for a `no rows found` response. Something like `400: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.` does not seem right for this situation.

Comment: There is a [host of 4xx error codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4). OP can choose the one that is most appropriate. Data inspection is certainly an option, but if the PHP script has a limited set of responses, using an HTTP code is a clean, efficient way to communicate.

Comment: @user2366551 The answer to your updated question is "yes". However, changing the question midstream requires all of the answerers to go back and update their answers. It may be something to avoid in the future.

Comment: Have you tried going to the script directly in your browser (without the AJAX call) to verify that the response code really is 400? You might have to set up a form to submit your POST data directly to the script for testing purposes.

Comment: Then your PHP script has other errors. Please turn on error reporting in your php.ini configuration file or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` near the top of your script. If you continue to have trouble with that part, please open a new question with complete details.

Comment: I figured it out, the HTML page that calls the ajax method has to opened from localhost !!

Answer (score 1):

Make your PHP script output something, preferably in JSON.

Like:

```
{ action: 'find_id', status: true }
```

Get the data from response, so you can see if an action was successful or not.

```
function(data){
  if (data.status){
    alert("Everything is OK") ;
  } else {
    alert("Failed") ;
  }
}
```